# Uploading video to Facebook album

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-graph-api, upload

I've created a Facebook album and have the album ID.  I'm able to upload a photo to the album using the /photos API.  But I can't upload a video using something like /videos API.  I get the error message:

"(#200) User does not have permission to post to target"

1) Is that even a supported API call?  I couldn't find much on Facebook's developer site on this.
2) Is it a permission flag problem?  I have publish_stream, photo_upload, video_upload, user_photos, user_videos all requested.  I don't know if photo_upload/video_upload are even proper ones, but saw examples from other sites about photo_upload so I just assumed there might be a video_upload.

Comment: The thing took out part of my notes, but I mean albumid/photos and albumid/videos.  I'm guessing albumid might only be for photos since I was able to send to me/videos fine.

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can upload video.

Make sure you are posting to a place where u get permission to do so.  You can see an example with code at http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/

code extracted below:

```
<?php 
$app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
$app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET"; 
$my_url = "YOUR_POST_LOGIN_URL"; 
$video_title = "YOUR_VIDEO_TITLE";
$video_desc = "YOUR_VIDEO_DESCRIPTION";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
   $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
     . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
     . "&scope=publish_stream";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
    . "&code=" . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?"
    . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc 
    . "&". $access_token;

echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" '.$post_url.' "  
     method="POST">';
echo 'Please choose a file:';
echo '<input name="file" type="file">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" />';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, posting to me/videos is working but do you know if posting to <album id>/videos is supposed to work as well?